# what to do when got error operator " required two operands?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

my question is about
i got the error said operator " required two operands
what should i do ?

```
 $user_id=Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
    $query = Appendix::find()
    ->andFilterWhere(['customer_id'=>$user_id])
    ->andFilterWhere(['status'== null]);
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `'status'== null` should be `'status'=> null`

Comment: yea when i do that there's no error but its not display what i want. its not include 'status' => null

Comment: You will need to do a raw where, as you can't test `status = NULL`, you need to check for `status IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong, What you are looking for can be done like the following way to check the column value for `null`.

```
->andWhere(['is', 'status', new \yii\db\Expression('null')]),
```

Comment: yea it didnt give any error but the output doesnt display at all. do you know why ?

Comment: you need to call `->all()` in the end